# how to edit android build configuration files

Tags: android, build, config

When using ant to build the project should I change the files like project.properties and local.properties manually? 
The comment at the beginning of the file clearly states that I should not.

I saw that some configuration are written in ant.properties.

How must I edit those files?

Comment: I had to edit the `project.properties` manually in order to include ProGuard in one of my projects and I simply disregarded the warning message, my changes where not erased. Did you try editing the ant file manually ?

Comment: Yes I did and it worked because I did not run any tool that could change it but I was wondering whether there is a better way to do it